# "MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'FunctionName' in params" UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'FunctoinName' found in params"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm new to AWS and try to learn, following the CDK workshop. In the [lesson about permissions](https://cdkworkshop.com/20-typescript/40-hit-counter/600-permissions.html) I receive below error while invoking Lambda function. I'm unable to figure out what exactly I'm missing here.

```
2021-12-24T22:51:39.682Z    f903da64-11f8-4294-8eeb-a02179c48dbd    ERROR   Invoke Error    {
    "errorType": "MultipleValidationErrors",
    "errorMessage": "There were 2 validation errors:\n* MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'FunctionName' in params\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'FunctoinName' found in params",
    "code": "MultipleValidationErrors",
    "message": "There were 2 validation errors:\n* MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'FunctionName' in params\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'FunctoinName' found in params",
    "errors": [
        {
            "errorType": "MissingRequiredParameter",
            "errorMessage": "Missing required key 'FunctionName' in params",
            "code": "MissingRequiredParameter",
            "message": "Missing required key 'FunctionName' in params",
            "time": "2021-12-24T22:51:39.624Z",
            "stack": [
                "MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'FunctionName' in params",
                "    at ParamValidator.fail (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:50:37)",
                "    at ParamValidator.validateStructure (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:61:14)",
                "    at ParamValidator.validateMember (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:88:21)",
                "    at ParamValidator.validate (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:34:10)",
                "    at Request.VALIDATE_PARAMETERS (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:132:42)",
                "    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)",
                "    at callNextListener (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:96:12)",
                "    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:86:9",
                "    at finish (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:386:7)",
                "    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:404:9"
            ]
        },
        {
            "errorType": "UnexpectedParameter",
            "errorMessage": "Unexpected key 'FunctoinName' found in params",
            "code": "UnexpectedParameter",
            "message": "Unexpected key 'FunctoinName' found in params",
            "time": "2021-12-24T22:51:39.624Z",
            "stack": [
                "UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'FunctoinName' found in params",
                "    at ParamValidator.fail (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:50:37)",
                "    at ParamValidator.validateStructure (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:77:14)",
                "    at ParamValidator.validateMember (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:88:21)",
                "    at ParamValidator.validate (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:34:10)",
                "    at Request.VALIDATE_PARAMETERS (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:132:42)",
                "    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)",
                "    at callNextListener (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:96:12)",
                "    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:86:9",
                "    at finish (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:386:7)",
                "    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:404:9"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "time": "2021-12-24T22:51:39.681Z",
    "stack": [
        "MultipleValidationErrors: There were 2 validation errors:",
        "* MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'FunctionName' in params",
        "* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'FunctoinName' found in params",
        "    at ParamValidator.validate (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:40:28)",
        "    at Request.VALIDATE_PARAMETERS (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:132:42)",
        "    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)",
        "    at callNextListener (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:96:12)",
        "    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:86:9",
        "    at finish (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:386:7)",
        "    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:404:9",
        "    at EnvironmentCredentials.get (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/credentials.js:127:7)",
        "    at getAsyncCredentials (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:398:24)",
        "    at Config.getCredentials (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:418:9)"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates that you have a typo in the params, `FunctoinName` instead of `FunctionName`.